# He's doing a lecture

Tags: word-usage

https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/lecture

He's doing a lecture on modern poetry.

So here what does "doing" mean here?

Answer (score 3):

"Doing" means "giving" here. He's the one who is *giving* a lecture. He is a speaker, not a student.
The verb "do" can often be used to replace another verb. I've found a relevant discussion -  please, check this: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/356416/use-do-instead-of-many-other-verbs.

For instance:

- Hey, John. **Do** the window. It's cold in here. (Close the window)
- Hey, John. **Do** the window. It's hot in here. (Open the window)
- Johanna, would you please **do** the dishes? The sink is full
  already. (Wash the dishes)

"Do the lecture" sounds quite similar to me. In my opinion, the verb "do" in our case replaces the verb "give" or "deliver" and makes it sound less formal.

We can also understand that "doing a lecture" means "giving a lecture" by referring to basic meanings of "do". I looked up in the Cambridge Dictionary: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/do  .

**do  (PERFORM)** - to perform, take part in, or achieve something

**do (MAKE)** - to make, produce, or create something:

(example) I can't go out tonight - I've got to **do** my history paper.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.

Comment: @Nathan Tuggy, sorry for posting a poor answer at first, I've corrected it. Hope it's better now.

Comment: and to add "Hey, John. Do the window. It's hot in here. (Open the window)"